# How to parameterize the locators?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, pageobjects

I am trying store all values required for locators in  Property File:

This is Property File:

```
url=https://www.google.com
value=search
```

This is my object repository class:

```
public class pageobjects extends helperclass{
public WebDriver driver;

By search  = By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='search12()']") //I am trying to insert helpclass method here.

public class pageobjects(Webdriver driver){ //creating constructor
  
 this.driver=driver; }

 public WebElement search(){
return driver.findElement(search);
}
}
```

Here I don't want to **hardcode** "Search" in my object repository file and in my testcase file so I trying to store in a Property File. I know that by using "load ()" and "getProperty()", I can read/load  Property File.

This is my helper class to consists of methods to store particular String value from Property file:

```
public helperclass { 
public properties prop;


static String search12() { 
prop=new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path of property file);
return prop.getProperty("value");
}

}
```

Error: The String //input[@aria-label='search12()'] is not valid Xpath expression.

Comment: You can create a helper class which would read properties file, and it would have a method which should return the value of a key.  https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ . Then you can call that class' method whenever you need to use these values.  Of course, moving locators out of the code is not a good practice.

Comment: @Turcia I updated my question with **Helper class**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this -

```
By.xpath("//input[@aria-label="+search12()+"]")
```